# Python: How to take control of the cursor if cursor is inactive for five minutes and pause the program (my python program) if user touches the mouse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I want to write a bot that will simulate mouse movements when user is away for more than 5 minutes and stay put when user takes control i.e. moves the mouse.
I have written following code as a part of the program.
[Here](https://github.com/ashneo95/kiosk/blob/master/gui%20V2.py) is the link to my old program which clicks at given points periodically. The problem with [this](https://github.com/ashneo95/kiosk/blob/master/gui%20V2.py) program is I have to start the program when I want to go somewhere and after returning close the program in order to resume working.

Here is the one of the module I wrote for the new program which detects whether mouse is moving or not.

```
import win32api
from time import sleep
print("starting engine.")
count = 0
while(True):
    savedpos = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    if count>20*5:
        break
    sleep(1)
    curpos = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    if savedpos == curpos:
        savedpos = curpos
        print("Mouse is steady.")
    else: 
        print("Mouse is moving.")
    count += 1
```

Comment: you already figured the biggest problem out, what's your question?

Comment: I am not able to write the code which will wait t minutes after user lefts the mouse and pause (the program) when user returns i.e. moves the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I wont be writing the code but I have the Idea to solve the problem
you use pyautogui.position() to keep checking the position and if it doesnt change position for 300 seconds you move it

Answer (score 0):

I wrote following code referring other Stackoverflow posts.
This code waits 4 minutes for mouse being steady. Whenever mouse is moved, timer is reset to zero.

```
import win32api
from time import sleep
import pyautogui as gui
print("starting engine.")
count = 0
savedpos = win32api.GetCursorPos()


def actions():
    print(gui.size())
    while True:
        #toast.show_toast("ROBOT V2 !", "Robot is active.", threaded=False, icon_path=None, duration=2)
        gui.click()        
        gui.press('home')
        gui.moveTo(541, 142, 0.25)  # Money Transfer dropdown
        gui.click()
        sleep(0.5)
        gui.moveTo(541, 172, 0.25)  # Money Transfer link
        gui.click()
        sleep(5)
        cond()


def cond():
    count = 0
    while True:
        savedpos = win32api.GetCursorPos()
        sleep(0.5)
        curpos = win32api.GetCursorPos()
        if savedpos == curpos:
            savedpos = curpos
            print("Mouse is steady. Elapsed time: ", (count+1)/2, " seconds.")
            count += 1
            if count >= 480:  # if count is greater than 60 it means timeout will occur after mouse is steady for more than
                # 240 seconds i.e. 4 minutes. (approx.)
                print("User away for more than 4 minutes, taking control of the system.")
                actions()
                break
            else:
                pass
        else:
            print("Mouse is moving.")
            count = 0

cond()
```

Comment: Do you have something similar for Mac OS. I can see that this is using win32api, so I'm assuming this works only on windows.